# Spring WebClient how to reduce DNS cache TTL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I'm using WebClient (from Spring-Weblux) and currently it caches DNS for 30 mins.

I don't see any information how to reduce this DNS cache.
**How can I reduce it to 30sec?**

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.create().responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(connectionTimeout))
                           .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout);


WebClient serviceWebClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(neweactorClientHttpConnector(client))
                           .baseUrl(deployedServiceHost).build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything that is related to DNS can be configured with `.resolver()`

there is method `cacheMaxTimeToLive()` in `NameResolverSpec`, from java doc:

> Sets the max time to live of the cached DNS resource records
> (resolution: seconds). If the time to live of the DNS resource record
> returned by the DNS server is greater than this max time to live, this
> resolver will ignore the time to live from the DNS server and will use
> this max time to live. Default to
> NameResolverProvider.Build.DEFAULT_CACHE_MAX_TIME_TO_LIVE.

So, try this:

```java
HttpClient.create()
        .resolver(nameResolverSpec -> nameResolverSpec.cacheMaxTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(...)));
```